# No default constructor found, and not serializable

Tags: c#, arrays, compilation, designer

I have tried so many times to get this to compile, what I'd like to do is have an array of names and extensions to be editable via designer, but when editing via designer, it throws the error :

Constructor on type 'Filter' not found.

and on compile:

Code generation for property 'ExtensionList' failed.  Error was: 'Type 'Filter' in Assembly 'Testing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.'

Can anyone help? This is the code I'm using:

```
    System.Collections.Generic.List<Filter> InternalExtensions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Filter>();

    [System.ComponentModel.Description(@"Sets a list of acceptable extensions to view.")]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<Filter> ExtensionList
    {
        get
        {
            return InternalExtensions;
        }
        set
        {
            InternalExtensions = value;
        }
    }

[Serializable()]
public class Filter : System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
{
    String Name;
    String[] Extensions;

    public Filter()
    {

    }       

    public Filter(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("FilterName", Name);
        info.AddValue("FilterExtensions", Extensions);
    }


   public void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
   {
       Name = (String)info.GetValue("FilterName", typeof(String));
       Extensions = (String[])info.GetValue("FilterExtensions", typeof(String[]));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's *all* of your problem, but your implementation of `ISerializable` is the wrong way round. You're meant to populate the *object* in the constructor, and the `SerializationInfo` in `GetObjectData`:

```
public Filter(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
   Name = (String)info.GetValue("FilterName", typeof(String));
   Extensions = (String[])info.GetValue("FilterExtensions", typeof(String[]));
}


public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("FilterName", Name);
    info.AddValue("FilterExtensions", Extensions);
}
```

I wouldn't have expected this to cause a problem at compile-time though... what kind of code generation is involved?

Comment: Yeah, I put that back in the constructor. The problem didn't change.

It doesn't stop it from running, it just displays this error message like 6 times and then it compiles.

Comment: @Fabian: Do you mean if you build it again it starts to compile? Is it a warning or an actual error?

Comment: It is displayed as a messagebox playing the error sound, but the app still compiles. The messagebox appears like 6 or 7 times while it is compiling.

Edit: It also does this when I save the project. I'm guessing this is coming from the designer, though it doesn't show this error when opening the property window in the designer, when I press the "add" button, it only complains of having no constructor.

Comment: Wow, now that I've saved and reopened Visual Studio, it doesn't complain about anything, but the resX file was screwed up, I manually deleted the key for ExtensionList and the Add button worked, but instead of having the values Name and Extension, the window only accepts the object type.

Comment: @Fabian: What happens if you build from the command line with msbuild?

Comment: Thanks man, I got it to work, the designer stopped throwing the No Constructor when I restarted Visual Studio, and though it corrupted my ResX file, I removed the data for ExtensionList and inside the Filter class, turned the declared string Name and string array Extensions into properties and now the designer displays both Name and Extensions in the collection window, again, thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: @Fabian: Glad to help, even though I still don't know exactly what was going on :)

Comment: Visual Studio choked up a bit, it never did seem to work well with ResX files, if you write a screwed up piece of code and let it generate code in the ResX file, it won't undo the code.

Restarting Visual Studio automagically made the No constructor error go away, and the Serializable error window go away, this is weird because VS usually doesn't do this. It wrote a bad thing in my ResX when I restarted and attempted to recompile, after removing the full reference in the ResX it works, so basically your implementation of Serializable worked, and I added properties to make it appear in designer

Comment: Ugh, is there anyway to make it save the data? I can add items as I wish but when pressing Ok in the designer, and reopening the property ExtensionList, there are no contents, but there are no compile problems or designer error windows either.

Comment: @Fabian: Have you tried just not implementing `ISerializable`, and relying not the default implementation you get from using the `Serializable` attribute?

Comment: It's not fixed but it does look like I don't need the class to inherit from `ISerializable`. So that's cool.